# Generate a set of numbers that have uniqueness on addition, subtraction, multiplication and division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

The problem is somewhat tricky. I would like to generate a set of number pairs $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)...$ so that each pair of numbers has uniqueness on all four computations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division).

For example, $x_1 = 2, y_1 = 2$ is definitely not a good choice here because $2 + 2 = 2 * 2. x_1 = 2, y_1 = 1$, and $x_2 = 1, y_2 = 2$ are also not good choices because $x_1 + y_1 = x_2 + y_2$.

For a better explanation of my question, please see the below picture. In short, every single cell value in the red box should be unique. For example, if I get the $v_1$. then I know it is and can only be from row $1$.

[image].

Hope my explanation is clear. Could anyone please provide me with guidance on how to generate a set of numbers like this or directions on where I should look into?

I'm not sure what tag should I use it with, please bear with me if I used any wrong tag.

Comment: Coincidences should be rare, so you can just generate the pairs and check, throwing out any that don't work.  What kind of numbers are you using?  Naturals?  Reals?  You can guarantee it by taking the square roots of different primes.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using naturals and I would like to generate probably ~1000 pairs with as least overhead as possible. So I'm trying to not do this with checking after generating. Could you please explain more about taking the square roots of different primes? Are you saying I should pick primes as the number in my pairs?

Comment: If you were using reals you could just use $\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \ldots$ and be guaranteed no matches at all.  If you are going to pick 1000 pairs is it so bad to generate 1100 and throw out 100?  Depending on how you pick the naturals (larger is better) the number thrown out should be much less than this.

Comment: For example: choose any number between $10^6$ and $10^7$ and any other number between $10^2$ and $10^3$.  Subtraction and addition always yield different numbers, roughly the size of the larger number; multiplication yields a much larger number; and division yields a much smaller number.

Comment: Based on your comment on Michael Carey's answer, it seems you want pairs $\{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)\}$ such that *all* $4n$ pairwise sums, difference, products, and quotients are different from each other. If that's the case, you should say so in your original post. At the moment, it reads as though you just need the four results to be different for *each* pair.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will edit my question and probably insert an image for better explanation.

Comment: You have accepted an answer that in a way is the opposite of what you're looking for (i.e., it will generate many collisions).

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't see Michael's doing anything wrong here. He suggested starting with (1(x), 2(y)) and doubling the values of y for every row. So that I have a sequence of (1, 2), (1, 4)... I don't see why it will generate a repeated value.

Comment: @romatomato Ah, I see, I misread the question. I thought you had a set of values $x$ and were generating pairs between them.

Comment: no problem at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let a = 1  b > 1 ; and a,b are natural numbers

a + b = b + 1 ≠ a + bn for n > 1

a - b = 1-b ≠ 1 -bn for n > 1

a*b = b ≠ a * (bn) for n > 1

a/b = 1/b ≠ 1/(bn) for n > 1

This suggests the sequence of pairs:

$a_n$ = (1,y), y > 1

$a_{n+1}$ = (1,2y)

So, we consider:

(1,2),(1,4),(1,8),(1,16).... etc

Note: As this seems to be an Excel application.

There may be rounding errors when trying to divide 1/x; which could result in duplicate terms. Double check your output to make sure everything is as desired.

Comment: Also, please have a look at the [MathJax tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll definitely look at the typesetting reference. As to the math, I think we are working with different interpretations as to what the question is. ( or my answer was unclear). (2,1) and (4,2) not part of my proposed sequence, so the equality of 2/1 and 4/2 shouldnt matter. Neither are (1,32) and (4,8).

Comment: Yes, my bad, I misinterpreted the question. This seems like a good way to go.

Comment: All good, I also misunderstood the question also!! I had a whole other incorrect answer that I deleted lol. The pair (1,1) has the problem in that 1*1 = 1/1, which breaks the condition that for all pairs, (x,y), x*y ≠  x/y. (1,2),(1,3) .... (1,n) is a great simplification though! if n > 1. far better for excel, as you could build longer sequences without worrying about rounding errors.